# Add SSL to Heroku app and godaddy - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, dns

I'm trying to setup SSL certs with heroku and godaddy. I've successfully created a cert with LetsEncrypt, and have received this message

```
Your certificate has been added successfully.  Update your application's DNS settings as follows
Domain                   Record Type  DNS Target
───────────────────────  ───────────  ─────────────────────────────────────
secure.lockdownjobs.com  CNAME        secure.lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com
www.lockdownjobs.com     CNAME        www.lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com
```

The part I'm struggling with is `DNS Target` how in godaddy do I point the domain at the DNS target?

Comment: You know that heroku offers free automated SSL encryption managment on all paid dynos ?

Comment: I honestly don't know that much about this stuff. This is my first go around if you couldn't tell. I have a cert, that's not the problem. at least I don't think. I just want to use it now. Which is what I'm struggling with.

Comment: @AlexanderLuna does this mean that we don't have to buy our own SSL certs from eg GoDaddy? or does that just mean that Heroku will "manage" it for us, once we buy it?

Comment: @bplittle It means that Heroku creates one for free for you. You don't have to buy one from Godaddy or any other provider. Heroku offers this through "Let's Encrypt" which is a place where you can get Free SSL certificates for non Heroku apps as well. You can use "Let's Encrypt" by your own and create an SSL certificate. You would have to download it and add it manually to your App but Heroku does this automatically as well so you don't have to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the CNAME in Godaddy. Go to your domain, click on DNS File settings and add a new CNAME:

```
CNAME
www
Target
secure.lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com
```

I recommend you read about how to add SSL certificate to Heroku:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#setting-up-ssl-on-heroku

And also the much easier way of doing it (Let Heroku do it):
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management

Comment: I thought I did? check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43302592/point-dns-to-ssl-cname-heroku-godaddy I posted a picture

Comment: Did you upload the certificate to Heroku ?

Comment: I think? I use this line with the CLI `heroku certs:info` I get this response ```Certificate details:
Common Name(s): lockdownjobs.com
Expires At:     2017-07-07 19:15 UTC
Issuer:         /C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
Starts At:      2017-04-08 19:15 UTC
Subject:        /CN=lockdownjobs.com
SSL certificate is verified by a root authority.```

Comment: In Go Daddy set the target as "secure.lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com" not "www.lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com", I updated my answer.

Comment: I removed that domain... Why wont `www.lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com` work?

Comment: I believe you have to use the secure DNS target for HTTPS. You also have to set in your config > environment > production.rb file " config.force_ssl = true" to change your traffic to HTTPS. Remeber also that it takes time for the changes to take effect (up to 48 hours).