# How to set up ssl on heroku app with a GoDaddy domain

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns

I have a herokuapp running with a GoDaddy custom domain, and I am trying to add an ssl. I followed the Heroku tutorial by upgrading to a hobby dyno and clicking on "configure ssl." I then chose the automatic option, and it told me to replace the DNS www.example.com with a long string that Heroku provided, but I am not sure where to do this. GoDaddy does not allow me to change the address to the string because it does not begin with www. Has anybody set up an ssl for a herokuapp with a GoDaddy custom domain who has experience with this?

Comment: Have you checked this (and the other links from it): [Add SSL to Heroku app and godaddy - Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43301203/2745495)? (it says "Rails" in the title but the steps should be the same regardless).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it a while back.

I set up the SSL on Heroku by upgrading the dyno to paid and used their SSL. The hard part would just be connecting GoDaddy and Heroku together.

All you need to do is go to Heroku and add a custom domain and copy the DNS.

Go to your DNS settings in GoDaddy and create a new record.

Type = CNAME

NAME = WWW

Points to = [DNS FROM HEROKU]

That should be all.

You should have something like this:

[image: sample]